# Javascript split and join in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

how can i write this code in PHP?
I tried several things but it wouldnt work.
Can u help me please?

```
return s.split(/\r?\n/).join("<br>");
```

Thanks!

Comment: PHP used to have `split` and `join` functions, but they were deprecated as being aliases for the much wider used `explode` and `implode` functions. http://php.net/split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you using regular expression. How about this one

```
echo implode(preg_split('/\r?\n/', $s), '<br>');
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP used to have `split` and `join` functions, but they were deprecated as being aliases for the much wider used `explode` and `implode` functions. [RTM](http://php.net/split)

What you're trying to do *can* be done using `implode`, `explode`, and `str_replace`. The latter should replace any `\r` characters (seeing as they're optional). You then can `explode` the string using `\n` as delimiter, and `implode` it again using `<br>`. But that would mean calling 3 functions, which is a bit redundant considering there is a single function that does *exactly* what you need: [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
return implode(
    '<br/>',
    //split on \n
    explode(
        "\n",
       //remove any \r chars
        str_replace(
            "\r",
            '',
            $s
        )
    )
);
//The results are the same as this clean, simple one-liner
return nl2br($s);
```

## Tl;tr

use `nl2br`, it's as simple as that, and it'll do exactly what you want, with the least amount of effort required.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
return implode("<br />", explode("\R", $s));
```

Where `\R` stands for any line break, `\n`  or `\r` or `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this :

```
return implode("<br />", explode("\r\n", s));
```

Comment: Check the regex: `\r` is optional, add a `str_replace` and explode on `\n` instead